# Script not working in Wordpress Header.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have placed the following script:

```
 if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1026) {   
  jQuery('.widgetable').scrollToFixed({marginTop:80,zIndex:9});
 }
```

But when i refresh the page the side bar is not scrolling, when i place this code into the chrome console it works without problem.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: You should add the code inside of: 

$( document ).ready(function() {
//code
});

Also if you provide more information should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're placing script inside your header.php file, its always good to wrap it inside `document.ready` event handler function.

```
jQuery(function() {
 if ( jQuery(window).width() > 1026) {   
            jQuery('.widgetable').scrollToFixed({marginTop:80,zIndex:9});
        }
});
```

This will make sure that the DOM is available when the function executes. Also the `scrollToFixed` plugin would have also finished loading by then.

Comment: Ill give this one a shot

Comment: Thanks mate this did the trick, i tried adding the jquery page function but it wasnt working thanks again :)